# Python calling an executable program

Tags: python

I need to call an executable program with Python, let's say:

```
C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v140\ansys\bin\winx64\ANSYS140.exe
```

I would need to have a txt file (`afshin.txt`) run with this executable application and then get the output file which is a txt file as well. In MATLAB for example it would be:

```
dos '"C:\Program Files\Ansys Inc\v121\ANSYS\bin\intel\ansys121.exe" -p AA_T_A -b -i afshin.txt -o file01.out' 
mod_1 = load('output_res.txt');
```

Would you help me to do it in Python?

Comment: in your example is `file01.out` same than `output_res.txt` ?

Comment: There are plenty of good examples in the [documentation of the `subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: yes, and a quick search gives a solution for the first part ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy), a sane wrapper around subprocess:

```
import envoy
r = envoy.run("C:\Program Files\Ansys Inc\v121\ANSYS\bin\intel\ansys121.exe -p AA_T_A -b -i afshin.txt -o file01.out")
mod_1 = open("output_res.txt").read()
print mod_1
```

Comment: Yes use a high level library not the low level library

Answer (score 1):

I have been use the following lines.

```
import os;
os.system("\"C:\\Apl\\ANSYS Inc\\v130\\ansys\\bin\\winx64\\ansys130.exe\" -b -j jobname -i InputFile.inp -o jobname.out");
```